# Pb with ImageMagick command

Tags: imagemagick, perspective

I'm trying to apply this code in my ".bat" file and my ASP.net projet:

```
convert checks.png -matte -virtual-pixel transparent -distort Perspective '0,0,0,0  0,90,0,90  90,0,90,25  90,90,90,65' checks_pers.png
```

The problem is that the result is like the original, no transformation to see, but i want to have a 3D Cover. I also tried many examples of the tutorial and they work only the distort Perspective?

I installed this version of ImageMagick : ImageMagick-6.7.2-0-Q16-windows-dll

Comment: I found the problem : in windows we must use the double quotes

Comment: When you find answers to your own question, it's okay to post them as an actual answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*(Answer pulled from OP's comment above)*

In Windows we must use double quotes:

```
convert checks.png -matte -virtual-pixel transparent -distort Perspective "0,0,0,0  0,90,0,90  90,0,90,25  90,90,90,65" checks_pers.png
```